# Fantasy book, quest to find gods but they are evil

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

Book is about the lost gods and for most of the book you want the gods to come back. Along the way there are reptilian people who are trying to help the gods return and you learn that the gods weren’t nice. In the end, the heroes lose and the gods return, cruelly using their power to suck the life force out of the people, but the people push back and kill or wound the gods.

I remember at the beginning these magicians go into the shop of a clairvoyant. She tells them she knows who they really are after she tells their fortune. That’s the first time we realize there are lizard people. They kill her. It was burned in my head.

Comment: Consider having a look at this [list of questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/40711) that could help you remember some more details, then you can [edit] them in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Is sounds like [Darkness at Sethanon](https://www.goodreads.com/bg/book/show/13813.A_Darkness_At_Sethanon) by [Raymond E. Feist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_E._Feist).

It is the 4th in a series that starts with [Magician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(Feist_novel))

The Pantathian Lizard people are basically a death cult trying to bring their 'gods' (an race called the Valheru - Dragon Lords) back into the world.  They pretend to be a foretold Moredhel (dark elf) leader to lead a war to capture Sethanon to recover an artefact to help bring back the Valheru.  The scene with the clairvoyant at the start was to help verify that the Morehdel leader was really the one of prophecy (and they killed her once she did so).

Comment: *A Darkness At Sethanon* was originally the third book in the series, since *Magician* was first published in a single volume. It only became the fourth when *Magician* in later editions was split into two books.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Agreed, when I read Magician there was only one part, but the Goodreads link I gave has it down as Riftwar #4 so I used that numbering to avoid confusion